# How can I use the 'try' and 'except' for positive scalars and positive vectors in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Imagine I have a function in python having 4 arguments, a,b,c,d. Now the variable 'a' should be a numpy array, 'b' should be either zero or a posive scalar, 'c' should be a strictly positive scalar and 'd' should be a strictly positive numpy array;
Now I would like to use the 'try' and 'except' syntax to create custom error messages, if the inputs do not fit; I managed it for the general numpy array but I failed to do something similar for the other variables - can someone maybe help me?

The function so far is given by:

```py
import numpy as np

def test(a,b,c,d):
    try:
        n=np.size(a,0)
        d=np.size(a,1)
    except:
        raise Exception('a must be a numpy n x d array')
```

Comment: You can raise exceptions inside `if` statements too. e.g. `if b < 0: raise Exception('b must be non-negative')`

Comment: `try/except` is for dealing with already raised exceptions, not for raising one by yourself - this you can do anywhere in the code.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that, thank you so much